# I don't want to reload cell in tableview

Tags: objective-c

when I scroll down the table view and I scroll up the table view, cells reloaded.

sciilicet,

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{}
```

this method recalling.

I don't want to reacall this method when I scroll up and go back the before table cells.

how can I do?

thanks for the help.

Comment: What does your cellForRowAtIndexPath method look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just the usual behavior of table.